# Will installing TWRP wipe my device?

Tags: rooting, twrp, magisk

So I've rooted my Galaxy S10 Exynos using Magisk and now I wish to install Twrp for easier updates flashing.

Will installing TWRP on my magisk rooted device wipe my data?

Thanks

Comment: Recovery is flashed to `recovery` partition (or `boot` partition on A/B devices). Your data is stored on `userdata` partition. Erasing/overwriting one won't harm the other. However unlocking bootloader is very likely to wipe your data. But it seems you've been through that already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. TWRP is only a custom recovery that replaces your stock recovery. But be sure to flash the right TWRP for your device.

Searching in this [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s10/development/recovery-twrp-3-3-0-galaxy-s10-exynos-t3924856)
using your model number
would be a good idea (On some devices it is possible that root is lost, and you may need to root again)

Comment: So I've read a little bit, and according to what I understand, updating the firmware would require me to use Odin again. So why install TWRP?

Comment: That is for you to answer! If you don't need TWRP to make nandroid backups or flash some zips, or keep changing  ROMs, you can well do without it. Personally I feel there isn't much use. It's upto you to decide

Comment: do not read a little bit, read carefully the whole opening post and make sure you understand. you will lose data and encryption support. afaik Magisk and TWRP lives in the same ramdisk, therefore TWRP should be patched with Magisk Manager (advanced settings - magisk in recovery)

Comment: nemesis-kernel might be interesting too (no button combo required for magisk) https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4020121